# Как добавлять шаблоны в DLE?

Tags: cms, dle

У меня dle 9.3. Я разрабатываю шаблон у себя на компе через denwer... Теперь к вопросу: как мне меню вставлять в статические страницы и чтоб статические страницы были по категориям (для каждой категории в статической странице было меню с разными пунктами). Скажите, как добавить меню в статистическую страницу, а дальше я сам разберусь.

Comment: @ХэшКод: предлагаю автоматический бан вопросов, с тегами "помогите", "хелп" и т.п. ;) <br/>
@автор  сформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос нормально и теги поставьте правильные.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Принято. Через какое-то время добавим фильтры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно тебя понял ты хочешь чтобы элементы меню изменялись в зависимости от открытой страницы сайта?

Могу подсказать только как вставить это меню на главную страницу сайта, сомо собой оно будет сквозным. Разложи файлы меню в соответствующие папки шаблона: .css файлы в папку style, .js файлы в папку - js, файлы картинок в папку - images. Проверь правильность путей к картинкам в файле стиля. Затем в файле main.tpl в перед закрытием блока <head> прописывай пути к используемым жаба скриптам и стилю менюшки. Пример:

```
<head>
<link href="{THEME}/style/стиль_менюшки.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/жаба_менюшки.js"></script>
</head>
```

и теперь в любое место своего шаблона вставляй код с твоим меню:

```
<div style="стиль_менюшки">код менюшки</div>
```

Comment: @ХэшКод: как насчет сделать нормальный редактор сообщений используя bbcode ?

Comment: @steff В настоящий момент изменение редактора не планируется.

Comment: жаль, мне нравится этот сайт, и буду страться помогать людям по мере своих знаний... но красиво отформатировать свое сообщение чтобы отделить "код" от просто слов хотелось бы более привычными способами... в итоге это лучше будет человеку который потом читает ответ на свой вопрос... даже набирая это сообщения хотелось выделить жирным пару слов но т.к. нет редактора этого сделать невозможно =(

Comment: А по мне так наоборот: с этими bb-кодами вечно фигня какая-нибудь.. народ путается в них и не закрывает вовремя и ерунда потом выходит.

Comment: Ну, как говорится на вкус и цвет фломастеров нет )
Еще было бы неплохо сделать некий раздел "How-To", в котором можно было бы публиковать свои наработки... вдруг кому пригодятся...

Comment: @steff Практически все, что делает bbcode, можно делать в markdown. Взгляните на [справку][1] по разметке. В частности, выделение жирным делается **так**.

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/markdown_help/